# How to use Mac Keyboard, on iPhone, with lightning cord?

Tags: iphone, mac, keyboard, software-recommendation, lightning

I am looking for a way to type on the Mac keyboard and have it type on an iPhone. I know there are many bluetooth Apps to do this, but I am using a typing script and bluetooth does not transmit the keys fast enough, hence why I would like a way to do this with a lightning cord.

Shouldn't really matter but I am on:

macOS High Sierra & iOS 11

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would probably be to buy a lighting to USB adapter like [this](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter?fnode=91) one as per [this](https://www.lifewire.com/connect-wired-keyboard-to-ipad-3968742) Lifewire article. The downside is that this sort of adaptor from apple usually carries a rather high cost with it. Therefore, I would recommend having a look around Amazon for a similar solution like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lightning-Adapter-Interface-Required-Support-White/dp/B07CFX7G54/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1532979262&sr=8-4&keywords=lightning%20to%20usb) one but be sure to check out the reviews!

Hope that helped.

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: Are you sure this would work with the keyboard? Additionally, just a suggestion since you are new: When ever you suggest any product that costs money your want to put a disclaimer that you are not affiliated with the company and won't financially benefit (unless you are and will in which case say that). Otherwise you risk being marked as spam.

Comment: I'm sure the keyboard will work with this adaptor and an iPad as stated in the article I linked; however, whilst I am not 100% sure this will work with an iPhone, I don't see too much reason why it wouldn't but I can't promise anything. Thank you for your note about adding a product association disclaimer.